# What is the limit of the Value Type BigInteger in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, numerical, value-type

As described in MSDN [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is :

> An immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose
>   value in theory has no upper or lower bounds.

As I can see BigInteger is a `ValueType`, as much as I know, a ValueType must have a **maximum size of 16 bytes**.

MSDN goes further saying :

> an OutOfMemoryException can be thrown for any operation that causes a
>   BigInteger value to grow too large.

and more :

> Although this process is transparent to the caller, it does incur a
>   performance penalty. In some cases, especially when repeated
>   operations are performed in a loop on very large BigInteger values

How could it store such big values, as big as `double.MaxValue + double.MaxValue` ?
I was told that it has `ReferenceType` obejects inside it, but all I can find here in its definition in VisualStudio is ValueTypes.

What's its real limit ? And even if doesn't have one, how can it "as a value type" manage to store all that amount of data ?

Comment: That 16 bytes is a (very) soft recommendation. You can have structs of many thousands of bytes, and structs with internal arrays (ref types).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> As I can see BigInteger is a ValueType, as much as I know, a ValueType must have a maximum size of 16 bytes.

No, that's not true. It's a *conventional* limit, but it's entirely feasible for a value type to take more than that. For example:

```
public struct Foo {
    private readonly int a, b, c, d, e; // Look ma, 20 bytes!
}
```

However, I strongly suspect that `BigInteger` actually includes a reference to a byte array:

```
public struct BigInteger {
    private readonly byte[] data;
    // Some other fields...
}
```

([Moslem Ben Dhaou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858585/1350209) shows one current implementation using `int` and `uint[]`, but of course the *details* of this are intentionally hidden.)

So the *value* of a `BigInteger` can still be small, but it can refer to a big chunk of memory - and if there isn't enough memory to allocate what's required when you perform some operation, you'll get an exception.

> How could it store such big values, as big as double.MaxValue + double.MaxValue ?

Well `BigInteger` is for *integers*, so I wouldn't particularly want to use it for anything to do with `double`... but fundamentally the limitations are going to be around how much memory you've got and the size of array the CLR can cope with. In reality, you'd be talking about *enormous* numbers before actually hitting the limit for any specific number - but if you have gazillions of smaller numbers, that obviously has large memory requirements too.

Comment: _"Moslem Ben Dhaou's answer shows one current implemeentation using `int` and `uint[]`, but of course, the **details** of this are intentionally hidden"_ [The Reference Source begs to differ](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs) ;)

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Well, they're "hidden" in that they're not part of the public API - they could be changed at any time.

Answer (score 7):

As a confirmation to the answer from Jon Skeet, I looked to the source code of `BigInteger`.  It actually contains two internal properties as follow:

```
internal int _sign;
internal uint[] _bits;
```

`_bits` is used by almost all private/public methods within the class which are used to read/write the actual data.

`_sign` is used to keep the sign of the `BigInteger`.

The private methods are extensively using binary operators and calculations. Here is a small list of constants used in the class that might reflect a bit the limits:

```
private const int knMaskHighBit = -2147483648;
private const uint kuMaskHighBit = 2147483648U;
private const int kcbitUint = 32;
private const int kcbitUlong = 64;
private const int DecimalScaleFactorMask = 16711680;
private const int DecimalSignMask = -2147483648;
```

PS: I should have commented on J.S. answer, but a comment is too short. To view the source code, either [download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319249/downloadable-browsable-version-of-the-net-framework-source-code) or decompile `System.Numerics.dll`.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs#38

Comment: No need to decompile anymore: [github/Microsoft/referencesource/System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs@4e6dea7a9c](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs)

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: BigInteger maxvalue is 2^68685922272

In .Net 4.7.2 BigInteger uses an uint array for bits.

An uint holds 32bits of data.

An array's max size is defined as `internal const int MaxArrayLength = 0X7FEFFFFF;`
7FEFFFFF = 2146435071

Now, to calculate: max size of array x capacity of each uint is: 2146435071 x 32 = 68685922272. But that's only the count of the bits in a BigInteger.

Which means BigInteger's max value is: 2^68'685'922'272 which is stupendusly large (used ' for easier readability).

If they ever decide to increase the array's max size, then it will also increase the max value for BigInteger.

Answer (score 3):

I just did some quick experiments on this. Max seems to be around 2^65,000,000,000 but actual practicality 2146435071

I get a System.OverflowException on the below at 0x1F. It overflowed between E FFFF FFE2 and F 7FFF FFE1. (or somewhere between 2^64,424,509,410 and 2^66,571,993,057)

```
// Test 1
BigInteger test = 1;
for (int i = 0x00; i < 0xFF; i++)
    test <<= 0x7FFFFFFF;

// Test 2
BigInteger.Pow((BigInteger)2, 0x7FEFFFF0); // OK - I think - never finished
BigInteger.Pow((BigInteger)2, 0x7FEFFFFF); // Immediate OutOfMemoryException
```

I should also note that while ~66,571,993,057 seems to be supported. The usefulness is more like 2^2146435071 because POWER and shifts don't seem to work with a POWER larger then 2,146,435,071(for POW() ) or a shift amount more than 2,147,483,647. Larger shifts can be done but it would take several rounds ruining efficiency.  And the other item is slow at those speeds - a single shift was taking about 7 seconds and BigInteger.Pow() took at least 5 minutes.

.Net 5, AMD Threadripper, 32GB RAM, Windows 10 x64