# Store 2^256 big integer value in variable

Tags: c#

Is there a data type to store 2^256 big integer numbers in variables in C#? As far as I know it exceeds the limit of BigInt.

Comment: 2^256 does not exceed the limit of BigInteger

Comment: The `BigInteger` type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds

Comment: Yes. there is such data type.

Comment: See: [What is the limit of the Value Type BigInteger in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21856753/8967612)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you're talking about exact integers: [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) is arbitrarily large. However, it may also be possible to just use a quad of `Int64`, depending on the exact operations you need to perform.